# Changing Background Image with set Interval

Tags: jquery

I've got the following function which changes that background image of 4 classes so one background goes green and then another making a loading bar:

```
clearInterval(start);
var i = 0;
function boxes() {

    in_loading = ".in_loading:eq("  + i + ")";

    $(".in_loading").css("background", "url(images/load_bar_green.png)  no-repeat");    
    $(in_loading).css("background", "url(images/load_bar_blue.png)  no-repeat");        

    if(i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }

}
var start = setInterval(function() {
    boxes();
}, 350);
```

When I keep clicking the submit button the 'flashing' alters as if their is 2 or more functions going at once. I've tried using remove() and display() but what I think I need is something to delay the start of the function and to 'clear' the function so multiple clicks doesn't screw it up!

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `clearInterval` in the click handler for the submit button. The way it is, the interval is never cleared (except before it is needed)

Comment: clearInterval(start) outside of the function after the click handler seems to break my code?

Comment: I get it now - jquery will give an error if the interval is not active before you clearInterval?